# Using Mapped Network Drive in Windows 7 and 8

Tags: windows, mapped-drive

I have an application that I am updating from Windows XP-Vista to Windows 7 and 8. The application previously used a mapped network drive to allow users to run the application stored on a main computer's drive from remote lab computers on the same network.

Alternatively, the lab computers could contain the application but use data files on the main computer shared via the mapped network drive.

Is this still possible to do in Windows 7 and 8? Is this the best way to do this now?

The goals is to provide a simple and easy way to share the application and data.

Comment: Of course.  It is just as unreliable as it always was.

Comment: Shares are prone to virus attack or distribution. Bad idea

Comment: The concept with this has been to provide bare-bones sharing. In that context is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Dave - it's a perfectly OK way to do it.  A bazillion businesses have been running applications off file shares for decades.